How to access App data files on the meta quest?
I am making a game using unity and in the game I'm parsing MIDI files and using the data to create a level. my problem is it is working on both unity and Windows build. However, when I build for the quest it doesn't work.
Does the path differs when building for the Meta Quest? or is it a permission issue ?
The way I'm accessing it is I put all my MIDI files in the "StreamingAssets" folder and try to access them from there. My logic is to read the titles of the MIDI files, add them to a menu inside the game and when the player presses on one it reads it and creates the level for them when they press play.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Android;  // For permission handling on Android
using UnityEngine.Networking; // For reading from StreamingAssets on Android

public class MidiFileLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<string> midiFilePaths = new List<string>(); // Store all MIDI file paths
    public GameObject buttonPrefab; // Assign a UI Button prefab with a Text component
    public Transform buttonContainer; // A parent object in the UI where buttons will be placed

    void Start()
    {
        // Request permission for external storage on Android
        if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
        {
            RequestStoragePermissions();
        }

        StartCoroutine(LoadMidiFiles()); // Use coroutine for loading MIDI files
    }

    // Coroutine to load MIDI files from StreamingAssets
    private IEnumerator LoadMidiFiles()
    {
        string midiFilesFolder = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "MidiFiles");

        // Load files from "Piano" and "Drums" subfolders
        string pianoFolder = Path.Combine(midiFilesFolder, "Piano");
        string drumsFolder = Path.Combine(midiFilesFolder, "Drums");

        if (!MidiReader.instance.isDrums)
        {
            yield return StartCoroutine(LoadMidiFilesFromFolder(pianoFolder));
        }
        else
        {
            yield return StartCoroutine(LoadMidiFilesFromFolder(drumsFolder));
        }

        PopulateMenu();
    }

    // Coroutine to load MIDI files from a folder
    private IEnumerator LoadMidiFilesFromFolder(string folderPath)
    {
        // On Android, use UnityWebRequest to load files from StreamingAssets
        string url = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, folderPath);

        if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
        {
            UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
            yield return request.SendWebRequest();

            if (request.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
            {
                string[] filePaths = request.downloadHandler.text.Split('\n'); // Parse file paths
                foreach (string path in filePaths)
                {
                    if (path.EndsWith(".mid"))
                    {
                        midiFilePaths.Add(path);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("Failed to load files from: " + url);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // For platforms other than Android, use standard file system access
            if (Directory.Exists(folderPath))
            {
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.mid");
                midiFilePaths.AddRange(files);
            }
        }
    }

    // This method will populate the menu with the MIDI file paths
    void PopulateMenu()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < midiFilePaths.Count; i++)
        {
            string path = midiFilePaths[i];

            // Instantiate the button inside the buttonContainer
            GameObject newButton = Instantiate(buttonPrefab, buttonContainer);

            // Set the button text to the MIDI file name
            newButton.GetComponentInChildren<TMP_Text>().text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);

            // Add a listener to the button to load the selected file when clicked
            Button buttonComponent = newButton.GetComponent<Button>();
            buttonComponent.onClick.AddListener(() => 
            {
                Debug.Log("Button clicked for: " + path);
                MidiReader.instance.StartReading(path);
            });
        }
    }

    // Request external storage permissions on Android
    private void RequestStoragePermissions()
    {
        if (!Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageRead))
        {
            Permission.RequestUserPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageRead);
        }

        // Optional: Check for write permission if needed
        if (!Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageWrite))
        {
            Permission.RequestUserPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageWrite);
        }
    }
}


You append the Application.streamingAssetsPath twice!

once in LoadMidiFiles at
  string midiFilesFolder = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "MidiFiles");

  // Load files from "Piano" and "Drums" subfolders
  string pianoFolder = Path.Combine(midiFilesFolder, "Piano");
  string drumsFolder = Path.Combine(midiFilesFolder, "Drums");


and then for some reason again in LoadMidiFilesFromFolder at
 string url = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, folderPath);



the folderPath at that point already has the Application.streamingAssetsPath pretended, so you can just use it and get rid of url entirely.

In general, do you actually have a dedicated file at these paths? I doubt that you can just shoot a request against a folder and it returns a string list of all contained files. Afaik that's not really how streaming assets work. You need to know already what paths exist. (Might be wrong on that though)

well you're correct. we struggled for a bit but figured out in the end. but with a round about way I guess. it's our first time for me and team members to work with VR so there's a probably better way than this. I posted the new code in another answer. Any help would be appreciated .

We struggled for a bit but figured out in the end. But with a round about way I guess.
Here is the new code my college made.
public class MidiFileLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<string> midiFilePaths = new List<string>(); // Store all MIDI file paths
    public GameObject buttonPrefab; // Assign a UI Button prefab with a Text component
    public Transform buttonContainer; // A parent object in the UI where buttons will be placed
    public string midiListFileName = "midi_list.txt"; // The text file that lists all MIDI files

    // UI elements for progress and debugging
    public Slider downloadProgressSlider; // Progress bar for file download
    public TMP_Text debugText; // TextMeshPro text for debugging and showing progress

    void Start()
    {
        // Request permission for external storage on Android
        if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
        {
            RequestStoragePermissions();
        }

        // Start loading MIDI file list
        StartCoroutine(LoadMidiFileList());
    }

    // Coroutine to load the list of MIDI files from StreamingAssets
    private IEnumerator LoadMidiFileList()
    {
        string midiListPath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "MidiFiles", midiListFileName);

        // Use UnityWebRequest to load the list file (for Android and other platforms)
        UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get(midiListPath);

        yield return request.SendWebRequest();

        if (request.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
        {
            // Parse the file list (assuming each file is on a new line)
            string fileList = request.downloadHandler.text;
            string[] lines = fileList.Split('\n');

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line.Trim()))
                {
                    midiFilePaths.Add(line.Trim());
                }
            }

            // Populate the UI with buttons for each MIDI file
            PopulateMenu();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Failed to load MIDI list: " + request.error);
        }
    }

    // This method will populate the menu with the MIDI file paths
    void PopulateMenu()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < midiFilePaths.Count; i++)
        {
            string path = midiFilePaths[i];

            // Instantiate the button inside the buttonContainer
            GameObject newButton = Instantiate(buttonPrefab, buttonContainer);

            // Set the button text to the MIDI file name
            newButton.GetComponentInChildren<TMP_Text>().text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);

            // Add a listener to the button to load the selected file when clicked
            Button buttonComponent = newButton.GetComponent<Button>();
            string fullPath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "MidiFiles", path);
            buttonComponent.onClick.AddListener(() => 
            {
                Debug.Log("Button clicked for: " + fullPath);
                StartCoroutine(LoadAndPlayMidi(fullPath));
            });
        }
    }

    // Coroutine to load and play a MIDI file
    private IEnumerator LoadAndPlayMidi(string filePath)
    {
        // Use UnityWebRequest to access the file in StreamingAssets
        UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get(filePath);

        // Reset progress bar and debug text
        downloadProgressSlider.value = 0;
        debugText.text = "Starting download...";

        request.SendWebRequest();

        // Update the progress bar while downloading
        while (!request.isDone)
        {
            downloadProgressSlider.value = request.downloadProgress;
            debugText.text = $"Downloading... {request.downloadProgress * 100}%";

            yield return null; // Wait until the next frame
        }

        if (request.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
        {
            // Save the downloaded file to persistentDataPath
            string tempFilePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, Path.GetFileName(filePath));

            // Write the downloaded data to a local file
            File.WriteAllBytes(tempFilePath, request.downloadHandler.data);

            // Call MidiReader with the file path of the saved file
            MidiReader.instance.StartReading(tempFilePath);

            // Debug: Notify user that the file is ready
            debugText.text = "Download complete!";
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Failed to load MIDI file: " + request.error);
            debugText.text = "Download failed: " + request.error;
        }

        // Reset progress bar after download
        downloadProgressSlider.value = 0;
    }

    // Request external storage permissions on Android
    private void RequestStoragePermissions()
    {
        if (!Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageRead))
        {
            Permission.RequestUserPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageRead);
        }

        // Optional: Check for write permission if needed
        if (!Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageWrite))
        {
            Permission.RequestUserPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageWrite);
        }
    }
}

